# Is it possible to convert a List to a Map using Orika?

Tags: orika

I am looking convert a List of custom objects to a Map of custom objects. I have a mapping defined with a custom method, but I keep getting a "cannot be cast to ma.glasnost.orika.MapEntry" exception. What is the proper way to go about converting a List to a Map in Orika?

```
mapperFactory.classMap(new TypeBuilder<List<com.printable.pti.NameValuePairType>>(){}.build(), new TypeBuilder<Map<String, com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField>>() {}.build())
.customize(new CustomMapper<List<com.printable.pti.NameValuePairType>,Map<String, com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField>>() {

@Override
public void mapAtoB(List<com.printable.pti.NameValuePairType> nameValuePairTypes,            
    Map<String, com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField> stringTemplateFieldMap, MappingContext context) {

        Map<String, com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField> toObject = new HashMap<String, com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField>();

            for(com.printable.pti.NameValuePairType nameValuePairType : nameValuePairTypes) {
                toObject.put(nameValuePairType.getName(),(com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField)map(nameValuePairType,com.kinetic.entity.TemplateField.class));
            }
        }
    }
)
.register();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [good example](https://gist.github.com/elaatifi/6269684) of how to map a list of elements to Map using Orika

Comment: I had to rework how I was approaching my Mappings, but this helped a lot. Thanks!